# Project Structure for Django Application

Tags: python, django, intellij-idea

I am new to Django and using Pycharm from IntelliJ as my IDE. When typing:

$ django-admin startproject mysite

the following project structure is generated:

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

This doesn't quite make sense since the files settings.py, urls.py, and wsgi.py are project specific, not app or package specific. Hence, they should go in the root folder just like manage.py. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: the structure you listed did not make much sense - can you reformat it. I would expect that the `startproject` command is correct, and therefore the `settings.py` is in the right place. I know you can have `urls.py` for each app - as each app can have it's own set of urls & sub-urls.

Answer (score 0):

That is the typical project layout, as you can see in [the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project).

You can change the layout if you want, but I recommend that you don't. If you moved `settings.py` that would confuse `manage.py`, if you moved `urls.py` then you'd have to update `ROOT_URLCONF` in `settings.py`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to store your `settings.py`, `url.py` and `wsgi.py` files in the root project directory with `manage.py` you can do so, but you will have to make a couple of alterations to the `settings.py` file and the way you run your project locally.

- use `python manage.py runserver --settings=settings` (instead of the default `python manage.py runserver -settings=mysite.settings`) to tell Django to use a settings file in the root project directory.
- change `ROOT_URLCONF` in `settings.py` from `'mysite.urls'` to `'urls'`.
- change `WSGI_APPLICATION` in `settings.py` from `'mysite.wsgi.application'` to `'wsgi.application'`.

Depending on preferences, it is actually relatively common to change the structure of your project (within reason). For example, the well-read Django book Two Scoops of Django suggests that you store different versions of your `settings.py` files in a `mysite/settings` as follows (ignoring urls/wsgi/apps for the moment):

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    settings/
        base.py
        local.py
        staging.py
        production.py
```